# Temporary message block

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

My question is this: is there a way to temporarily block messages from a single contact and receive the messages later? If a contact is placed on the blocked list, the messages are no longer received; but they will stay so and not appear at a later time. If the contact is placed on do not disturb, there is simply no notification and the texts are still received. If the phone is put into Airplane Mode and is not connected to wi-fi, no messages are received at all. Is there a middle way between these two where the contact messages are blocked for the current time being and received later?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You can schedule do not disturb but not schedule a change of a contact from favorite to not favorite, so that option blocks all non-favorites on a temporary basis.